Sphinx 3.7 search prioritising proximity and exact matches
I'm trying to prioritize search results in Sphinx Search based on two main factors:
Proximity of matches to the start of a field or document
Exact matches (higher weight for exact matches)
I'm using Sphinx version 3.7.x.
Here's an example scenario:
Scenario
I have a Sphinx index (products_index) with fields like name and title. Here's a sample query:
sql
SELECT * FROM products_index 
WHERE MATCH('^Book') 
OPTION ranker=expr('sum(full_field_hit)');

This gives me results like:
name    title   weight()
Book of Dreams      1.0
Book of Shadows     1.0
Book of Wisdom      1.0

This works fine for prefix searches, but I'd like to improve ranking in the following ways:
Prioritize results where the match occurs closer to the start of the name field.
Prioritize exact matches over partial matches.
For instance, if I search for Book of Wisdom, the query should prioritize Book of Wisdom over other results like Recipe: Book of Wisdom.
More examples of what I want:
If I search for "Book" I'd like a the first result to be something called "Book" (Exact match) if it exists, and then Book X, Book Y, etc. and never something like Other Book (unless all Book* have been returned already).
If I search for Cookies, and there's only a book called Book of Cookies, in that case it should be returned and always before other results like: This is the best all-time Cookies book (since cookies is less close to the beginning).
It should also work with partial matching like if I put Boo it should return Boo*, etc.
In my mind it shouldn't be that difficult what I'm asking for but I've been unable to make it work unless I combine multiple queries which seems suboptimal and inefficient.
What I've Tried:

Basic Ranking Expression:
OPTION ranker=expr('sum(full_field_hit)');


This uses full_field_hit to rank based on how many fields contain matches.

Adding Exact Matches and Proximity:
OPTION ranker=expr(' (exact_hit * 200) + (1000 / (1 + full_query_pos)) + sum(full_field_hit) ');


This should:

Reward exact matches with higher weights (exact_hit * 200).
Penalize matches that occur further from the start of the field (1000 / (1 + full_query_pos)).
Use full_field_hit as a fallback factor.

Error:
ERROR 1064 (42000): index 'products_index': unknown column: full_query_pos


Testing with field_start for Proximity:
OPTION ranker=expr(' (exact_hit * 200) + (1000 / (1 + field_start)) + sum(full_field_hit) ');

This also failed with the same error about field_start not being recognized.

Using Only exact_hit and full_field_hit:
OPTION ranker=expr(' (exact_hit * 200) + sum(full_field_hit) ');


This worked, but proximity to the start of the field was not factored in.

Checking Documentation for Proximity Factors:
Based on Sphinx Documentation, I tried adding attributes like position or offset in the index definition. However, I couldn't find clear documentation or examples for implementing them.

Alternative Approach with Prefix Matching in SQL:
If prefix matching was not sufficient, I considered splitting the query into two parts:
SELECT * FROM products_index WHERE MATCH('^Book') UNION ALL SELECT * FROM products_index WHERE MATCH('Book') AND NOT MATCH('^Book') LIMIT 20;


This would combine exact matches and fallback results. However, Sphinx doesn’t support UNION directly.

Other Ranking Factors:
I tried enabling proximity_weight or similar expressions but couldn't get start-of-field proximity to work with my setup.

All in all I don't know what I'm doing, and could do with some help , after wasting my time with chatgpt i thought of come here as most of things I tried errored or don't work the way I expect.
Thank you!
